# Custom domain setting godaddy and azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have domain from Godaddy and hosting is from Azure.

i want custom domain setting for that i have read [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

My website is opening using both  www.domainname.com and domainname.com
but social media are not working.

so my question is in azure i have added www.domainname.com or both ?

if i add only domainname.com then nake domain will give 404 error

please help me for this.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so my question is in azure i have added www.domainname.com or both?

Yes, you should add both domains on Azure portal. Azure web app will check the host name and compare it with the host names set on Azure portal.

In addition, The www CNAME record should be bind to the default domain of your web app. For example, agentsdeal.azurewebsites.net

> but i am using aspnet identity now problem is if i login using agentsdeal.com not login in www.agentsdeal.com i thing azure is making different instants for each domain

You need to set the CookieDomain in app.UseCookieAuthentication which written in Startup.Auth.cs file. Code below is for your reference.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieDomain = ".agentsdeal.com"
});
```

Comment: Thanx for replay
its work for me but i am using aspnet identity 
now problem is if i login using agentsdeal.com not login in www.agentsdeal.com

i thing azure is making different instants for each domain

Comment: You could fix this issue by setting CookieDomain in Startup.Auth.cs file. Please see sample code from the updates of my reply.